# Static Variables Among Parent & Child Class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to have the Parent class have a variable, and then that class will be able to set that variable to whatever value it wants.

Then in that class there will be another class which i want to have access to that variable, so both can read/write anything and it will be from the same source.

(The variable in this case is IVideoDriver* from Irrlicht, so a pointer to a driver if that matters).

I have tried many things, setting it to static in public on the parent class.
This only gives me linking errors which tells me nothing (Except that it doesn't work).

I also tried something like this:

```
   class Parentclass
{
public:
    IVideoDriver* driver;

    class Childclass
    { 
    iVideoDriver* ddriver = Parentclass::driver;
    }

}
```

This only gives me errors when the Childclass is trying to use it. I guess it's because the pointer get's corrupted as it's pointing towards something that may have changed.

So what am i missing here?

UPDATE:

Here is an example of what Doesn't work when using Static, it just complains about linking problems.

```
    class PlayerClass
{
public:
    PlayerClass(IVideoDriver*,SColor, int, int);
    static IVideoDriver* driver;
public:

     class TailClass
     {
     public:
     };

};
```

//Removed much from the code which doesn't have anything do do with the problem.

Comment: Funny, you're talking all about `static`, and that keyword doesn't appear even once in your code. You are not showing the part where you initialize that pointer anywhere in your code, so we're left to assume that you are **not** initializing it, hence, what do you mean by "the pointer gets corrupted"??? It is in a "corrupted" state (i.e., junk) to begin with.

Comment: Do you want the child class to be a member of the parent class? Or do you want the child class to *inherit* from the parent class? In the second case the child class will automatically have access to `public static` members.

Comment: The code is just one of many examples i have tried. I have used Static as i stated in my text.  The pointer is initialized outside the class in the main file. Then i link it through the constructor of the Parent class and there it basically does (ParentclassDriver = MainDriver). So it's just pointing to the other pointer (if this can be made smoother it would be great though). The pointer getting corrupted is just an assumption, but nothing ever get's wrong in the Parentclass which has the pointer to the Original pointer. There it goes exactly as predicted.

Comment: @eigenchris Don't know what you mean with being a member of the parent class (not that good at classes overall, new to c++ as well). But i simply want it to work as a global variable. Both classes has access to the same source. If it was an int both could do, GlobalInt = 10, and it would change for both classes.

Comment: @barakmanos I just tried and normal stuff seems to work. static int for example works fine. So it must be something with IVideoDriver, does it has to do with it being from a shared library perhaps?

Comment: I think you should take the time to sit down and learn how classes in C++ work. In particular, you should learn the difference between class *composition* and class *inheritance*. You could pick up a good book or try reading tutorials at http://www.learncpp.com/

Comment: @eigenchris do know the basics about parent -> child, private,public,protected. So for normal things everything is fine, i can do static, global or whatever. But this has something to do with using shared library. From reading around it seems it's not possible, at least not without some "hackish" way for making it work. Thanks for the link though will look to see what i can learn:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I know what your problem is, although I hope i'm not too late. I have had a bit of experience with this and what you should do is just have one class that contains all of the irrlicht variables and then make another declaration of that class so you can access them anywhere. (Enough of my confusing talk, here's code.)

Define the desired variable as static in a .h file:

```
class MyIrr
{
public:
static MyIrr* myirr;
static IVideoDriver* driver;
}
```

Define the variables in the cpp file (as swang said)

```
#include "MyIrr.h"
MyIrr* MyIrr::myirr;
IVideoDriver* MyIrr::driver;
```

Then you should be able to just include MyIrr.h in any other class and access the driver, I know its different from your original question, but its a work around.

```
//In a random cpp file
#include "MyIrr.h"

void Something(){
MyIrr::driver->beginScene(true, true, video::SColor(255, 200, 200, 200));
}
```

Comment: I actually kinda do like this now. Not exactly but very similar (that i have like a middle man handling all the interactions). So will take this as an answer as it explains how to use "Global Variables" in a good way so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

The linking error is probably complaining about you not initialising the static variable, in the cpp file you should do this:

```
IVideoDriver* PlayerClass::driver = new IVideoDriver(/*whatever parameters*/);
```

Comment: From the looks of it it works is i set a global static variable. Though it doesn't work as intended then, still wondering why as it works in the parent class but not the child even though the use the same global static variable. "new" doesn't work with this, so initialing it is not an option as it needs stuff during runtime inserted.

Comment: You don't have to initialise it using new, but you must define your static variable. In your code you simply declared it, the definition has to be in the cpp file.

Comment: confused. Do i have the static in the PlayerClass header and then in both the parent and child class i define it? Does't make sense. I get that global variables works  (though you don't need to define them in the .cpp files). If you don't mean define as in initialize. Cause i can't initialize a static public IVideoDriver that's in a class (think it's because it's from a external library .dll). (hope i am not completely off;P)

Comment: I'm afraid you are bit off. Check this faq for static member: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/link-errs-static-data-mems.html